# What could cause the Intel Turbo Boost Technology Monitor 2.0 to stop working?

Tags: windows-7, intel-core-i7, turbo-boost

The Intel Turbo Boost Technology Monitor ver. 2.0 is (in my limited opinion) a really basic non-user configurable program.

Its crashed on me twice in the last 2 weeks.   What could cause it to "stop working"?

Comment: When you were doing what?

Comment: Editing a keyboard shortcut to open a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reinstall the application downloading the latest version from [Intel web page](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-031038.htm). Perhaps some configurations were broken.